# recurrence or closed formula for determinant

Tags: calculus, matrices, determinant

Consider the following matrix

$$
\begin{equation}A_{n} := 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1} & -p & \dots  & 0  &\dots &0    \\
-q & a_{2} & -p &0  & \dots  & 0    \\
0 & -q & a_{3} &-p  & ~...  & 0    \\
0 & 0 &-q &a_{4} &-p   & 0    \\
0  &\vdots    & \ddots & -q & a_{n-1}  & -p \\
0  &0 &0 &\dots &-q  &a_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$

where $a_{j},p,q \in \mathbb{R}$, $a_{j} \neq 0$ for all $j = 1,2,...,n$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We have

$$
\det A_{n} = \frac{1}{x_{n}} \det A_{n-1} - pq \det A_{n-2}.
$$

Now consider the vector $b := (q,0,..,0,p)^{t} \in \mathbb{R}^{r-1}$ and define $[A_{n}]_{i}$  to be the matrix obtained from $A_{n}$ except that I replace the i-th column of $A_{n}$ with $b$ for $i=1,...,n$. Define for simplicity

$$
\begin{equation}D_{k,n} := 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{k} & -p & \dots  & 0  &\dots &0    \\
-q & a_{k+1} & -p &0  & \dots  & 0    \\
0 & -q & a_{k+2} &-p  & ~...  & 0    \\
0 & 0 &-q &a_{k+3} &-p   & 0    \\
0  &\vdots    & \ddots & -q & a_{n-1}  & -p \\
0  &0 &0 &\dots &-q  &a_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
where $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$, $k \leq n$.

Now for example for $i = 1$ I would get after expanding by the first column

\begin{align}
\det([A_{n}]_{1}) &= 
\begin{vmatrix}
q & -p \\
0 & a_2 & -p \\
0 &-q & a_3 & -p \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & -p \\
& & & -q & a_{n-2} & -p \\
& & & & -q & a_{n-1} & -p \\
p& & & & & -q & a_n
\end{vmatrix}
&= q \cdot \det(D_{2,n}) + p^{n}
\end{align}

For $i = 2$ I have also compute the determinant after expanding by the second column. I get

\begin{align}
\det([A_{n}]_{2}) &= 
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & q \\
-q  & 0 & -p \\
0   & 0 & a_3 & -p \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & -p \\
& & & -q & a_{n-2} & -p \\
& & & & -q & a_{n-1} & -p \\
& p& & & & -q & a_n
\end{vmatrix}
&= q^{2} \cdot \det(D_{3,n}) + a_1p^{n-1}
\end{align}

Up to this point I thought I have the following formula

$$
\det([A_{n}]_{i}) = q^{i} \cdot \det(D_{i+1,n}) + a_1 ... a_{i-1}p^{n-i+1}
$$

But then I compute $\det([A_{n}]_{3})$ and after expanding by the third column I get

$$
\det([A_{n}]_{3}) = q^{3} \cdot \det(D_{4,n}) + a_1 a_2 p^{n-2} - p^{n-1}q
$$

So my first thought is not correct. My question is, wether there is a closed formula for $\det([A_{n}]_{i})$. Or maybe a recurrence equation? I Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2951369/265466) to [the almost identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2951334/265466) that you asked earlier gives you a recurrence for the determinant and a link to more general results for a tridiagonal matrix.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Where can I find the link?

Comment: The word “recurrence” in the first sentence is a link.

Comment: there is no link

Comment: Sure, there is. It links to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant.

Comment: please read my question carefully. If you have no idea, then do not make me confuse

Comment: this is a slightly different question than the one I asked previously